# excel hyperlink function to variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of cells with hyperlink function. One example: `A1=HYPERLINK("T:\projekt1\61VWAus.xlsx";"61VWAus.xlsx" )`. I need go through each cell and check each hyperlink if it is valid file. How can I get the hyperlink `"T:\projekt1\61VWAus.xlsx"` to a variable from the formula value? Do I have to use string operation to get it or is there any direct function to get only hyperlink?
Thanks

Comment: `.Hyperlinks(1).Address`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
Function check_hyperlink(rng As Range) As Boolean
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim str_Hyperlink As String
Dim exists As Boolean
Dim str_form As String
Dim arr_str_form As Variant

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    str_form = rng.Cells(1, 1).Formula
    
    If Left(str_form, 10) = "=HYPERLINK" Then
        arr_str_form = Split(str_form, Chr(34))
        str_Hyperlink = arr_str_form(1)
        exists = oFSO.FileExists(str_Hyperlink)
        
        If exists Then
            check_hyperlink = True
        Else
            check_hyperlink = False
        End If
    Else
        check_hyperlink = False
    End If
End Function
```